# Faster way to write the following code

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, numpy, pandas

I'm in the process of parsing data, and writing it to csv files before importing them to a database. During the parse, I'm keeping a list of authors names (which tend to get repeated alot). I"m generating two csv files, one in which I have two colums: author's id (which I manually generate through a counter), and author's name. The second csv file, has two columns as well, author_id and publication_id. I publication could have numerous authors and an author could have numerous publications.

Now here is my issue. The code I wrote is taking waaaay too long to parse. I have over 2 million records I'm going through, and it's going at a pace of about 6,000 records an hour. I believe the biggest issue is that I have to search if the author has already been previously found before I write him.

This is how I do it:

```
#authors_list is a list that has the authors of the current publication I'm parsing. 
#all_authors is a list that has all the authors found so far.

j=0 #keeps track of authors index in all_authors list
flag=0

for a in authors_list:
    #check to see if authors already exists
    allauthors = np.array(all_authors)
    if a in allauthors[:,1]:
         flag = 1
         k = 0 #k gives me current index of found author
         while flag and k<len(allauthors):
             if allauthors[k][1]==a:
                 index = k
                 flag = 0
             else:
                 k+=1
         print "Author exists: ", allauthors[k][1]
         aup.writerow([k,pid])
    else:
         all_authors.append([j,a]) 
         au.writerow([j,a])
         aup.writerow([j,pid])
```

I feel there has to be a much faster way to achieve this check. Maybe using pandas? Or numpy in a better way? I'm quite new to both.

Comment: As a first step you could load the first csv and then drop the duplicate authors and write this out as the clean csv, this sounds like a messy many to many relationship, it sounds like the publication is the unique thing here so you probably want to repeat the publications for each author

Comment: You are dealing what essentially  "foreign keys" and with an astounding big number of records: its way past the point you should put it in an SQL database, not in CSV files. It is not hard to do, and even sqlite which is built-in in Python will serve you well.

Comment: @jsbueno I originally had it insert directly into an sql database. But that was taking even longer. Then someone told me it might be faster to just parse it neatly into a csv file and just use a command like .import on sqlite3 to import it directly into my tables. That's what I'm doing here.

Comment: ok  - I figured out some of what makes it take long in there - TL;DR: numpy is not what you need. I will render an answer that mightbe of use.

Comment: Even if you can't implement/dislike my answer, I  suggest you to remove "numpy" from the title of the question. It is not the right tool for the job here - you are doing textual data processing

Comment: will do ! thank you for clearing this up for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The major problem there is that for each author in each article you ar eperforming a linear search in all authors  you have so far.

That alone has O(N²) complexity - but worse, you are recreating the data-structure for each author name with the line `allauthors = np.array(all_authors)` and you are actually lucky if you are getting "6000/hour" (it is more likely 6000 on the *first* hour :-)  )

Sometimes, simple is better. Other times, simpler is much, much better.
It should still be possible to write things directly to SQL, avoiding the pass through CSV files you are seeing here, but there is too little context in your question to write such an example.

```
#authors_list is a list that has the authors of the current publication I'm parsing. 
#all_authors is a list that has all the authors found so far.

last_author_id = 0 #keeps track of authors index in all_authors list
all_authors = {}
for author in authors_list:
    if author in all_authors:
        author_index = all_authors[author]
        print "Author exists: ", author_index
    else:
        last_author_id += 1
        all_authors[author] = author_index = last_author_id
        au.writerow([author_index, author])
    aup.writerow([author_index, pid])
```

Note the  major changes:

- not using Numpy at all. Numpy has great features for numeric processing - linear text search have no improvements when using numpy
- not recreating the data structure on each author name
- Using a Python Dictionary (or a set) to store the authors names, instead of a sequence, Numpy or not,  changes from a linear search with time O(N) to a fixed hash search with time O(1)

Also a possible issue here: I am keeping naively all authors and created ID in a dict, in memory. That should be ok for ~GB RAM class server/desktop and 2 million 1 line text records - but should these numbers change, writing everything straightway to an SQL server would fix that (Any DBMS is supposed to keep the latency for searches low (if you have an index for the author name), and the correct caches in a transparent way for simple queries like this)

Comment: You're AWESOME! I tried it your way and it's a million times faster! :))))) Can't thank you enough :)))) Side note: there was an small error in the code: author_index = all_authors(author) should be author_index = all_authors[author]